# How can I limit percentages to each individual facet instead of across facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

new to R, so my code may not be as efficient as possible.

Each facet represents a different seminar. Participants of the seminars rate the seminar. Right now, the percentage for each rating (e.g., "Helpful", "Not Helpful", etc.) for each seminar is being calculated as a percentage across ALL the seminar. In other words, the graphs show that ~16% of respondents of ALL the four seminars rated the "Managing Your Nonprofit" seminar as "very helpful".

However, I need it to limit the ratings to the individual seminar (i.e., the graph should show that 100% of the respondents who attended the "Managing Your Nonprofit" seminar rated it as "Very Helpful".

Below is my code. I think the issue may be with `geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))`, but am not sure. What's the cleanest way to make the graph I want within my existing approach?

```
webinar_rating_graph <- response_master_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=`How would you rate the content of the webinar?`)) +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(str_wrap(Webinar, 15))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
           fill="skyblue", color="black") +
  labs(title="Ratings of Webinars as Percentage of Respondants", y="Percentage of Respondants") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
    strip.text=element_text(hjust=.5, size=8), 
    axis.text=element_text(hjust=.5, size=5), 
    axis.title=element_text(size=8)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels=scales::wrap_format(4), 
    limits = c("Very Helpful", "Somewhat Helpful", 
               "Neither Helpful nor Unhelpful", 
               "Somewhat Unhelpful", "Very Unhelpful"))

webinar_rating_graph
```

Here is the resulting graph:

[image: 1]

Comment: Not sure about the cleanest approach ... but I would suggest to summarize your dataset before plotting using group_by + summarie + mutate. This is at least in my opinion the easiest and most simple approach.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try that approach

Answer (score 2):

As @stefan commented, you can summarize the data outside of ggplot and then plot the calculated percentages. That will in general give you the greatest flexibility (see the example at the end of this answer).

To do everything within ggplot, you can use the internally computed variable `..prop..` to calculate percentages. We also need to set the `group` aesthetic to group by the faceting variable(s), in order to ensure that percentages are calculated *within* each panel, rather than across all panels.

Here's an example using the built-in `mtcars` data frame. We facet by column `vs`, so we use `group=vs` within `geom_bar` to ensure that percentages are calculated within each `vs` facet:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop.., group=vs)) +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(vs)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent, limits=c(0,1), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to pre-summarize the data, you can do it like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  # Get counts of each group
  group_by(vs, cyl) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  # Get percent within each level of vs
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, pct)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_grid(cols=vars(vs)) +
    scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent, limits=c(0,1), expand=c(0,0)) +
    theme_bw()
```